# passing custom object to jar file invoked from URLclassloader

Tags: java, jar, urlclassloader

I have written an application which invokes a jar file which is placed outside of my class path and then invokes a method from URLCLassLoader api provided by java.
I can invoke the methods from jar which has no arguments, but when i try top invoke a method which takes an argument, i get "No such method" exception

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: plugins.PluginTest.sendOTP(com.ca.pas.plugin.bean.RequestBean)
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethod(Class.java:2130)
at com.ca.pas.plugin.controller.PluginController.invokePlugin(PluginController.java:45)
at com.ca.pas.plugin.service.PluginServiceImpl.sendOTP(PluginServiceImpl.java:22)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
```

## Jar file code

```
package plugins;

public class PluginTest {

public ResponseBean sendOTP(RequestBean rbs){

    System.out.println(rbs.getOrb().getMobileNumber());
    ResponseBean rb = new ResponseBean();
    return rb;
}

}
```

The above jar file has its own requestBean class defined.

## Main application which invokes jar file

```
package com.ca.pas.plugin.service;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.ca.pas.plugin.bean.RequestBean;
import com.ca.pas.plugin.bean.ResponseBean;
import com.ca.pas.plugin.controller.PluginController;

/**
 * @author jamju02
 *
 */
@Service("pluginService")
public class PluginServiceImpl implements PluginService{

@Override
public ResponseBean sendOTP(RequestBean requestBean) {
    PluginController pc = new PluginController();
    return pc.invokePlugin(requestBean);
}

}




package com.ca.pas.plugin.controller;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.reflect.Constructor;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLClassLoader;

import com.ca.pas.plugin.bean.RequestBean;
import com.ca.pas.plugin.bean.ResponseBean;

/**
 * @author jamju02
 *
 */
 public class PluginController {

/**
 * This method is used to invoke plugin class dynamically
 * @param requestBean : This object contains all parameter to
 * complete the request
 * @return responseBean : This object contains the response from vendor
 */
public ResponseBean invokePlugin(RequestBean requestBean){
    URLClassLoader urlClassLoader = null;
    ResponseBean responseBean = null; 
    Object[] obj = {new RequestBean() };
    Class params[] = new Class[obj.length];
    try {
        urlClassLoader = new URLClassLoader(new URL[]{new URL("file:///C:/Users/jamju02/Desktop/today/otp.jar")});
        if(urlClassLoader != null){
             Class pluiginClass = urlClassLoader.loadClass("plugins.PluginTest");

             if(pluiginClass != null){
                // Create a new instance from the loaded class
                 Constructor<?> constructor = pluiginClass.getConstructor();

                Object classobject = constructor.newInstance();
                params[0] = RequestBean.class;
                    Method method = pluiginClass.getDeclaredMethod("sendOTP", params);
                    method.setAccessible(true);
                    responseBean = (ResponseBean) method.invoke(classobject);
                    //System.out.println((String) method.invoke(classobject));
             }else{
                 System.out.println("class file name not found in jar file");
             }

        }else{

        }



    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InstantiationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally{
        try {
            if(urlClassLoader != null){
                urlClassLoader.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return responseBean;
}
```

Comment: Try to list all methods in the class: `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(pluiginClass.getDeclaredMethods()));`.

Comment: Use this instead of getDeclaredMethod -> `pluiginClass.getClass().getMethod(name, parameterTypes)`